# Get focused node in FancyTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I am trying to get the current focused node when a button is clicked.

I've tried calling [getFocusNode()](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/Fancytree.html#getFocusNode) in the following function on a click handler.

```
function deleteFolder() {
    var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getFocusNode");
    console.log(node);
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: no such method 'getFocusNode' for fancytree widget
>   instance

On closer inspection of the documentation it says that the getFocusNode method is yet to be implemented.

Is there any other way that I can retrieve the focused node from an external function?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `getActiveNode()`:

```
function deleteFolder() {
    var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree"),
        node = tree.getActiveNode();
    console.log(node);
}
```